# StreamSocketListener randomly receive empty from client on Raspberry Pi 3 (IoT Core UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I am testing a very simple web server code (either copied it from MSDN sample or somewhere I forgot),  I am running it on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with IoT Core v.10.0.16299.309.  I did everything properly including disposing the socket on each request and the code works most of the time.

I only have ONE client, sending 3 very simple HTTP GET requests to this web service every 30 seconds,  just a simple URL like this: http://serverIP/get?id=123  It returns the result properly but RANDOMLY during the hour, the request object is empty for some strange reason. I couldn't figure it out why.

```
private StreamSocketListener _listener;
private int _bufferSize = 8192;

public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    _listener = new StreamSocketListener();
    _listener.ConnectionReceived += HandleRequest;
    await _listener.BindServiceNameAsync("9080");       
}

public async void HandleRequest(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
  try 
  {
    StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder()
    using (IInputStream input = args.Socket.InputStream)
    {
         byte[] data = new byte[_bufferSize];
         IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
         uint bytesRead = _bufferSize;
         while (bytesRead == _bufferSize)
         {
            await input.ReadAsync(buffer, _bufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial);                        
            request.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));
                    bytesRead = buffer.Length;

             // Some other code here to process the request object
             // and respond it back to the client. They are irrelevant.

          } // while
      } // using
   } // catch
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // Log here
   }
   finally 
   { 
       args.Socket.Dispose();
   }
} // method
```

I thought that there is something wrong with Threading, so I disabled most of the async and await.  Interestingly, the result is A LOT BETTER. The request object is 99% fine. Within 12 hours, there were only 3-4 times where the request was empty. I don't think this is the right solution... but I really get stuck on this one and couldn't figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

```
private StreamSocketListener _listener;
private int _bufferSize = 8192;

public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    _listener = new StreamSocketListener();
    _listener.ConnectionReceived += HandleRequest;
    _listener.BindServiceNameAsync("9080");     // ** No "await"
}

 // ** No "async"
public void HandleRequest(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
  try 
  {
    StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder()
    using (IInputStream input = args.Socket.InputStream)
    {
         byte[] data = new byte[_bufferSize];
         IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
         uint bytesRead = _bufferSize;
         while (bytesRead == _bufferSize)
         {
            // ** No "await"
            input.ReadAsync(buffer, _bufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial);                        
            request.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));
                    bytesRead = buffer.Length;

             // Some other code here to process the request object
             // and respond it back to the client. They are irrelevant.

          } // while
      } // using
   } // catch
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // Log here
   }
   finally 
   { 
       args.Socket.Dispose();
   }
} // method
```

Comment: `taskInstance.GetDeferral()` - this gets a temporary object that will be GCed eventually. When the object is GCed, it (probably) automatically completes the deferral (some objects do, some don't). Can you try holding on to the deferral (eg, in a class field) and then explicitly `Complete` it when you're done?

Comment: Hi Peter.. thanks for the reply.  think I've tried it too, after _deferral.Completed() executed,  the StreamSocketListen will no longer listen.  If I comment out _deferral.Complete() but leave the class variable, the behavior is exactly the same as what I described. Correct me if I misunderstand what you mean.

Comment: @userb00, did you add `Connection: close` in the header of response?

Comment: Yes, I did send the respond as HTTP/1.1 200 OK,  then Content-Length:xxx,  then Connection: close

Answer (score 1):

The [IInputStream.ReadAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.iinputstream.readasync) documentation has some interesting information that might help:

> Always read data from the buffer returned in the
>   IAsyncOperationWithProgress(IBuffer, UInt32). Don't assume that the
>   input buffer contains the data. Depending on the implementation, the
>   data that's read might be placed into the input buffer, or it might be
>   returned in a different buffer. For the input buffer, you don't have
>   to implement the IBuffer interface. Instead, you can create an
>   instance of the Buffer class.

**The provided buffer might not contain the data.**

You can either use the return buffer and extract the data from it or use [DataReader.ReadBuffer()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader.readbuffer#Windows_Storage_Streams_DataReader_ReadBuffer_System_UInt32_) (or [DataReader.ReadString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader.readstring) in your case) to get the data from the stream.

In general, it is easier to use a [DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader) to read the data from a stream than using the low level API.

You code becomes

```
 byte[] data = new byte[_bufferSize];
 IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
 uint bytesRead = _bufferSize;
 while (bytesRead == _bufferSize)
 {
    var readFromStreamBuffer = await input.ReadAsync(buffer, _bufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
    var readBytes = readFromStreamBuffer.ToArray();            
    request.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readBytes, 0, readBytes.Length));
    bytesRead = readFromStreamBuffer.Length;
  }
```

Or with [DataReader.ReadBuffer()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader.readbuffer#Windows_Storage_Streams_DataReader_ReadBuffer_System_UInt32_):

```
 byte[] data = new byte[_bufferSize];
 IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
 uint bytesRead = _bufferSize;
 var dataReader = new DataReader(input);
 while (bytesRead == _bufferSize)
 {
    await dataReader.LoadAsync(_bufferSize);

    var readFromStreamBuffer = dataReader.ReadBuffer();
    var readBytes = readFromStreamBuffer.ToArray();            
    request.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readBytes, 0, readBytes.Length));

    bytesRead = readFromStreamBuffer.Length;
  }
```

Or with [DataReader.ReadString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader.readstring):

```
 byte[] data = new byte[_bufferSize];
 IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
 uint bytesRead = _bufferSize;
 var dataReader = new DataReader(input);
 dataReader.UnicodeEncoding  = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
 while (bytesRead == _bufferSize)
 {
    await dataReader.LoadAsync(_bufferSize);
    request.Append(dataReader.ReadString(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength));

    bytesRead = readFromStreamBuffer.Length;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent, that is VERY INTERESTING information on ReadSync()...  that actually help shed some light on the issue!  I was pulling my hair and last night, I ran out of idea and changed my code to use Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead() just to read one line for testing (for what I need is actually good enough) and it seems to be stable, no random empty incoming request.  I will post my code, it's very simple.  But I will definitely try your suggestion.

Comment: Your proposal is working since the "old" .Net Stream created by AsStream() is hiding the complexity of IInputstream.ReadAsync(). You should use directly the UWP DataReader instead of creating a temporary Stream that will ultimately end in a Stream/Data Reader instance :)

Answer (score 0):

Ran out of idea, I changed my code to use Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead() instead, then use .ReadLineAsync() just to read the first line only for testing. It seemed to be stable, passing 12+ hours there wasn't an empty request!!!

For what I need, this is actually fine because I am not really building a full function web server, so I don't need to get the complete request. All I need is to get the HTTP GET QueryString and pass the parameters to the GPIO of my Raspberry Pi.

As Vincent suggested, .ReadAsync() has some very interesting behavior. I will definitely try his suggestion later.

```
public async void HandleRequest(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    string requestString;
    try
    { 
        Stream inStream = args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inStream);
        requestString = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

         // Some other code here to process the request object
         // and respond it back to the client. They are irrelevant
    } // catch     
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // Log here
    }
    finally 
    { 
       args.Socket.Dispose();
    }
}
```